# Eslint inline comment to allow double quotes in javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, eslint

I have some stub json data in a javascript file. I would like to preserve it as  valid JSON with double quotes. Eslint expects single quotes in javascript files and I do not want to change that rule globally.

How do I tell eslint inline to allow double quotes within a given code block without placing `//eslint-disable-line` at the end of each line?

I've tried placing the following at the top of the file with no success:

```
/*eslint quotes: [2, "double"]*/
var sampleData = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "bar"},
    ...
];
```

Even it that did work, I only want to address double quotes in the code block containing double quotes, not the whole file.

Comment: not JSON if there's other code around it... In that case, lint is right: use single quotes on object literals. besides, if this is a choice you made, then why can't you simply ignore the suggestion? lint is NOT a validator, its to catch coding mistakes and ambiguities, and other stuff you didn't mean to write.

Comment: @dandavis Regardless, how do I tell eslint to ignore that block of code? I copy data from JSON files frequently. Rather than doing a mass find and replace, I would like to use the data copied from valid JSON documents.

Comment: afaik, you can't change options for a block of code. you can import the data from JSON in code. or, as the lint docs state: "If you do not need consistency in your string styles, you can safely disable this rule."... it sounds like you do not need/want consistency...

Comment: As of right now this use case is not supported but we have an issue open to dicuss this: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1766

Comment: Thanks, @Gyandeep. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable certain rules for a block by placing a disable rule before the block, and an enable block after it again:

```
/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */
var sampleData = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "bar"},
    ...
];
/* eslint-enable no-alert, no-console */
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is cumbersome to find a specific syntax to disallow a specific eslint rule. In this situations you can use "global" disabling for a code block as the following:

```
/*eslint-disable */

const sampleData = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "bar"},
    ...
];

/*eslint-enable */
```